# Variable to disk of VM in vboxmanage like {{.Name}}

Tags: virtualbox, packer

I would like to use `vboxmanage modifyhd /path/to/thedisk.vdi --compact` with packer in `vboxmanage_post` to shrink the size of the vm which will be exported afterwards. E.g.

```
"vboxmanage_post": [
    ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "4"],
    ["modifyhd", "/path/to/thedisk/as/variable", "--compact"]
],
```

The packer script is run from different systems so the path to the disk can vary.

I know of `{{.Name}}` to refer to the VM by name. Is there a way to refer to the disk likewise?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
"vboxmanage_post": [
    [ "modifyhd", "--compact", "{{pwd}}/output-{{build_name}}/{{.Name}}.vdi"]
]
```

It worked for me when running packer in the same directory as the template. If you don't run packer in the same directory as the template you may need `{{template_dir}}` instead of `{{pwd}}`. I didn't test that use case.